# I have a Loop with a get Request that I get a 403 error after 5 loops

Tags: python, python-requests, screen-scraping

My script is looping through  a get request and concatenating them into a pandas data frame to export to excel. Everything works good until the loop goes through 5 times, and then the site gives a 403 error. Somehow the site know once i have made requests for 50k rows and gives the 403 error. Is there a way around this that anyone can share with me please.step is a variable at the end of URL string that tells how many rows to bring back. I can only do 10k at a time or the it lags so much it wont work.SKIP is a another variable in the URL string that skips forward a set amount of rows. The script is super slow too if anyone can give any hints on how to make it faster too it would be much appreciated. Thanks.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import json
import pandas as pd
import requests
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
executor_url = driver.command_executor._url
session_id = driver.session_id

#put the url/website you are trying to scrape from here > this should be the url you go to when you login
driver.get(r"http://10.131.178.162:9090/xGLinear/login.html")

#waits 60 secs to give you time to login manually
time.sleep(60)

#this will copy all the cookies and login info you need from chrome and now you can start using requests
cookies = driver.get_cookies()
s = requests.Session()
for cookie in cookies:
    s.cookies.set(cookie['name'], cookie['value'])

res = s.get(r"http://10.131.178.162:9090/orders/OrderStatus?$dataAccess=ALL&$&$dateRange=ordered&$endDate=06%2F28%2F2020&$filter=%7B%22operator%22:%22AND%22,%22criteria%22:%5B%7B%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22fieldName%22:%22lineMode%22,%22value%22:%22R%22%7D,%7B%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22fieldName%22:%22creditHold%22,%22value%22:%22N%22%7D,%7B%22operator%22:%22OR%22,%22criteria%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22status%22,%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22value%22:%22AP%22%7D,%7B%22fieldName%22:%22status%22,%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22value%22:%22SC%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D&$skip=0&$sortBy=%5B%22-key.orderlineId%22%5D&$startDate=06%2F22%2F2020&$top=10000")

data = json.loads(res.text)


TotalR=data['totalRows']

SKIP=10000

skip1=10000
total_count= int(TotalR/skip1)
step=10000

Count=0

df = pd.DataFrame()
try:
    while Count < total_count : 
        res1= s.get(f"http://10.131.178.162:9090/orders/OrderStatus?$dataAccess=ALL&$skip={SKIP}&$dateRange=ordered&$endDate=06%2F28%2F2020&$filter=%7B%22operator%22:%22AND%22,%22criteria%22:%5B%7B%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22fieldName%22:%22lineMode%22,%22value%22:%22R%22%7D,%7B%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22fieldName%22:%22creditHold%22,%22value%22:%22N%22%7D,%7B%22operator%22:%22OR%22,%22criteria%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22status%22,%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22value%22:%22AP%22%7D,%7B%22fieldName%22:%22status%22,%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22value%22:%22SC%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D&$skip=0&$sortBy=%5B%22-key.orderlineId%22%5D&$startDate=06%2F22%2F2020&$top={step}")
        data1 = json.loads(res1.text)
        for d in data1['data']:
            dict_new = pd.DataFrame(d)
            df = pd.concat([df,dict_new])
        SKIP+=10000
        Count+=1

except:
    print(res1.status_code)
        

final=pd.DataFrame(data['data'])
final1=pd.DataFrame(final)
final2= pd.concat([df,final1])        
final2.to_excel(r'C:\Users\c\Desktop\xg.xlsx',index= False)
```

Comment: 403 is a 'forbidden' error. You should probably wait inbetween requests. I think the site is recognizing that you are making to many request in a short time spam and bloking your requests (probably some kind of ddos protection that you are triggering).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to work around this, you just reached your limit.

A solution would be to look at the documentation, and know how often this count resets.
Then, you'll be able to add a wait, in order to keep the good rythm and get rid of 403 error code.

```
import time
```

```
try:
    cpt = 0
    while Count < total_count : 
        res1= s.get(f"http://10.131.178.162:9090/orders/OrderStatus?$dataAccess=ALL&$skip={SKIP}&$dateRange=ordered&$endDate=06%2F28%2F2020&$filter=%7B%22operator%22:%22AND%22,%22criteria%22:%5B%7B%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22fieldName%22:%22lineMode%22,%22value%22:%22R%22%7D,%7B%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22fieldName%22:%22creditHold%22,%22value%22:%22N%22%7D,%7B%22operator%22:%22OR%22,%22criteria%22:%5B%7B%22fieldName%22:%22status%22,%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22value%22:%22AP%22%7D,%7B%22fieldName%22:%22status%22,%22operator%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22value%22:%22SC%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D&$skip=0&$sortBy=%5B%22-key.orderlineId%22%5D&$startDate=06%2F22%2F2020&$top={step}")
        data1 = json.loads(res1.text)
        for d in data1['data']:
            dict_new = pd.DataFrame(d)
            df = pd.concat([df,dict_new])
        SKIP+=10000
        Count+=1
        cpt += 1
        if cpt == 5:
            cpt = 0
            time.wait(x) // X is how many seconds you'll need to wait

except:
    print(res1.status_code)
```